# how to close landscape mode just for normal layout?

Tags: java, android

I have an app which needs to close landscape mode just for normal layout and large layout has both landscape and portrait. how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to disable landscape mode for an activity you can declare this line in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
android:label="@string/name"
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Comment: I do not close hole an activity. I want to close just for normal layout.